# Set isConfirmed to true after timer runs out on SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using `sweetalert2` when confirming an input from user. I am using a dialog with two `buttons` , `confirm button` and `cancel button`, also I added a timer. When submit button is clicked everything works fine ( `ajax` is called ) but when timer runs out I want the same result as `confirm` button. I have tried adding `Swal.isConfirmed = true`, `result=true` but didn't get desired one.

```
Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Дали сакате да ги зачувате промените?',
                    showDenyButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: 'Зачувај',
                    confirmButtonColor: '#00CA4E',
                    denyButtonText: `Откажи`,
                    denyButtonColor: '#FF605C',
                    html: '<strong></strong> секунди.<br/>',
                    timer: 3000,
                    didOpen: () => {
                       timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                            Swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector('strong')
                                .textContent = (Swal.getTimerLeft() / 1000)
                                    .toFixed(0)
                        }, 100)
                        
                    },
                    willClose: () => {
                        clearInterval(timerInterval);
                        Swal.isConfirmed = true;
                    }
                }).then((result) => {
                    /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        console.log('confirmed');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "@Url.Action("SubstitutionAddPlayers","Scoreboard")",
                            data: {
                                jsonSubstitution: substitution,
                            },
                            success: function(data) {

                            },
                            error: function(req, status, error) {
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                        })
                        //Swal.fire('Saved!', '', 'success' )
                    } else if (result.isDenied) {
                        //Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
                    }
                })
```

I want when timer runs out, result in `then` to be true and `ajax call` to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If a `SWAL2` is *dismissed* from a timer, you can use `result.isDismissed` the same way as `result.isConfirmed` in any conditional statement.

```js
if (result.isDismissed) { 
  // .. code if timer is dismissed
}

if (result.isConfirmed) {
  // .. code if timer is confirmed
}
```

###### This is the ***result*** response if you remove all buttons and let it be:

```js
{isConfirmed: false, isDenied: false, isDismissed: true, dismiss: 'timer'}
```

*So try adding*

```js
if (result.isDismissed) {
  console.log('confirmed');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("
    SubstitutionAddPlayers ","
    Scoreboard ")",
    data: {
      jsonSubstitution: substitution,
    },
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(req, status, error) {
      console.log(msg);
    }
  })
  //Swal.fire('Saved!', '', 'success' )
}
```

Note: Consider disabling    outside click on that specific one maybe.